# Display current TTY/PTY in Terminal title

Tags: bash, prompt, window-title

I was trying to figure out how to make the current TTY session appear in the current Terminal window title bar by customising my `.bashrc` file, but I seem to be having a little trouble getting this to work.

I tried doing it like this;

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a | $(tty | cut -d/ -f3,4)\]$PS1"
```

but that doesn't give the desired result when I do that. instead it goes like;

```
| pts/0user@hostname ~$
```

in the opening terminal screen instead of to title bar like so;

```
user@host ~ | pty/0
```

in my `.bashrc` file it looks like this

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a | $(tty | cut -d/ -f3,4)\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

- -

Fixed with this.

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w | $(tty | cut -d/ -f3,4)\a\]$PS1"
```

thanks to @Gilles for pointing that out in their post which made it little more clear what needed to be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the window title, emit the [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#how2_title) `\e]2;TITLE\a` where `\e` and `\a` are the escape and bell character respectively. Since you're doing this inside the bash prompt, the escape sequence must be within `\[…\]` to tell bash that this doesn't produce any output inside the terminal.

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to truncate the `/dev/` prefix, and call `tty` once and for all since it won't change.

```
TTY=$(tty)
PS1="\\[\\e[2;${TTY#/dev/}\\a\\]$PS1"
```

Comment: Where does the `TTY` variable come from? I don't seem to have it set on any of my systems (Debians, some CentOS, Bash on all of them, some under `screen`. zsh seems to set it, though). However, Bash (4.3) has the `\l` prompt escape for `basename of the shell's terminal device name`, but with device names like `/dev/pts/14` it somewhat annoyingly shows only the number.

Comment: @ilkkachu My bad, I made a mistake when I checked: indeed zsh sets it but bash doesn't.